# given a square matrix, what's the expected number of cells that is simultaneously the biggest value in its row and column?

Tags: graph-theory, expected-value

the NxN square matrix represents a graph actually. the number in a non-zero cell represent the weight of the edge. If a cell is zero then there is no edge between the corresponding nodes.

If the matrix is generated randomly. We count the number X of cells who are both the biggest value in its row and the biggest value in its column.

what's $E[x]$ ?

I am clueless. Can anyone share some ideas?

Comment: You need more information than "the matrix is generated randomly" to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the weights are all i.i.d. and from a distribution that makes probability 0 for any entries being equal.

Let $X_{ij}$ be the random variable that is $1$ if entry $(i,j)$ is larger than any other entries in its row and its column, and $0$ otherwise. We have $E[X_{ij}]=\frac1{2n-1}$.

Now note that your $X$ is the sum of all the $X_{ij}$, and expectation is linear. So you can just add all the expectations for each of them.